# Improve performance during add controls on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, code-behind

I have problem with performance during add controls to grid. When I set to add 100 controls it take almost 2 seconds in Windows Phone and it freezes UI. Is there any other way to add custom controls to grid? Here is my code:

```
private void generateGrid(int size)
{
    int buttonsInColumn = 5; 
    SmallButtonControl smallButton;
    buttonEdge = screenWidth / buttonsInColumn;

    for (int i = 0; i < buttonsInColumn; i++)
        grChoolseBoard.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
    for (int j = 0; j < size / buttonsInColumn; j++)
        grChoolseBoard.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });

    for (int j = 0; j < size / buttonsInColumn; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonsInColumn; i++)
        {
            smallButton = new SmallButtonControl() { Width = buttonEdge, Height = buttonEdge };
            smallButton.Text = (j * buttonsInColumn + i + 1).ToString();
            smallButton.ButtonBackground = getColorAndEnableState(j * buttonsInColumn + i + 1, _level+1,ref smallButton); 
            smallButton.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, i);
            smallButton.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, j);
            grChoolseBoard.Children.Add(smallButton as SmallButtonControl);
            smallButton.Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(GoToBoard_Tapped);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# Forms, to avoid latency while adding many controls, `SuspendLayout();` to ignore updating the UI while the controls are being added, then `ResumeLayout();` signals the UI to start displaying changes again.  I'm unsure if Windows Phone development has the same feature.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was try with `await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High`, but it not enought, because time for adding controls to layout is the same.